# How can I write an exception stack trace in erlang after catching it?

Tags: exception, erlang, stack

Suppose I have something like this :

```
try code_that_fails()
catch _:_ -> .....
```

How do I print the stacktrace in the catch block? That block catches all exceptions, but I don't know how to print the stack...

Can you help me?

Comment: Francesco, if you are satisfied with one of the answers, please mark it as proper/satisfying answer

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From Erlang 21.0 onwards, there's a new official way to get the stack trace. An optional pattern match in the [try expression](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#try) on the third parameter in the exception, which will contain the stack trace:

```
try
   code_that_fails()
catch
   _:_:Stacktrace ->
      erlang:display(Stacktrace)
end
```

### Older versions (OTP 20 and below)

For versions of Erlang/OTP 20 and below, you need to use [get_stacktrace/0](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#erlang:get_stacktrace-0), which allows you to get the stacktrace of the last exception in the calling process:

```
try
   code_that_fails()
catch
   _:_ ->
      erlang:display(erlang:get_stacktrace())
end
```

Answer (score 7):

An answer for your question is:

```
io:format("Backtrace ~p~n", [erlang:get_stacktrace()])
```

The current function is at the head of the list. Read more in `man 3erl erlang` or [erlang:get_stacktrace/0](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#get_stacktrace-0)

Answer (score 6):

In your example, you don't need the `try`; you can just do

```
result = (catch code_that_fails()).
```

If an exception is raised, `catch` returns a tuple that contains the  [error code and stack trace](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/errors.html#exit_reasons).

Note that this is generally considered bad practice as it can mask exceptions. The stacktrace approach described in another answer is almost certainly what you want.

`try` is an extension of the original `catch` functionality; if you use it, you need to specify clauses for each exception type you would like to catch, and handle them appropriately. See sections 6.18/6.19 of the [Erlang reference manual](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/part_frame.html) for details and clear examples.

Comment: Just using `catch` is generally considered bad form. If you don't know that you want to catch *every* exception, you probably don't want it. It can make some bugs a lot harder to find.

Comment: @Adam Lindberg: Thanks - that would explain the downvotes. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you guys!! :)