# How to catch Exception Message in Erlang?

Tags: exception, erlang

This is the Exception message thrown by Gen_server when its not started.

```
(ankit@127.0.0.1)32> R11 = system_warning:self_test("SysWarn").
** exception exit: {noproc,
                    {gen_server,call,
                     [system_warning_sup,
                      {start_child,
                       {system_warning_SysWarn,
                        {system_warning,start_link,[{system_warning_SysWarn}]},
                        permanent,10,worker,
                        [system_warning]}},
                      infinity]}}
     in function  gen_server:call/3
     in call from system_warning_sup:'-start_child/1-lc$^0/1-0-'/1
     in call from system_warning:self_test/1
(ankit@127.0.0.1)33> R11.
* 1: variable 'R11' is unbound
```

Now, What I want to do is to catch this exception message & put into variable R11 (showed above as unbound). I want to do so because if gen_sever is not started then I want to start after getting this message. I also tried using handle_info but not able to trap the exception or may be not able to implement it correctly. Can any body please help me with this problem providing some code for example.

Comment: Found one Question related to my Question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335758/how-can-i-write-an-exception-stack-trace-in-erlang-after-catching-it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both the answers from @W55tKQbuRu28Q4xv and @Zed are correct but a little terse. :-)

There are two ways to locally catch an error: `catch`and `try`. Both will also catch non-local returns generated by `throw`.

`catch` is the older and simpler of the two and has the syntax `catch Expr`. If an error occurs in the expression being evaluated then `catch` returns `{'EXIT',ErrorValue}`, otherwise it just returns the value of the expression. One problem with it is that there is no way to see how the error return value has been generated so it can easily be faked in the expression. In the same way you can't see if the return value comes from a `throw`. N.B. this is **not** a bug but a feature. Also it is a prefix operator with a low priority so you would normally use it like:

```
R11 = (catch system_warning:self_test (....))
```

to avoid confusion. This was a mistake, it should have been `catch ... end`.

`throw` is more complex and allows you much greater control over over what to catch and how to handle both the normal returns and error/non-local returns. See the manual for a full description. @Zed's example shows the simplest case which catches everything.

Comment: Must have picked this up from Java, but I never liked the old catch syntax... exactly because of the "feature" you mention :)

Answer (score 5):

```
> try                                        
>   R11 = system_warning:self_test("SysWarn")
> catch                                      
>   Ex:Type -> {Ex,Type,erlang:get_stacktrace()}                       
> end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 'catch':
R11 = catch system_warning:self_test (....)

Comment: (zerg@casper)1> case catch drmaa:start () of
(zerg@casper)1> E -> io:format ("~p~n", [E]) end.
{'EXIT',{undef,[{drmaa,start,[]},
                {erl_eval,do_apply,5},
                {erl_eval,expr,5},
                {erl_eval,expr,5},
                {shell,exprs,6},
                {shell,eval_exprs,6},
                {shell,eval_loop,3}]}}
ok
(zerg@casper)2>

Comment: Thanks man... and sorry... I was not aware of much fact about catch thing that it can also be written like this and I tried & it didnt worked . :(